# How can I perform SNMP command for several OIDs at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I have a MIB table that I want to be able to edit. The following code performs the task well. What I would like to know is if there is a way to do it all in one set command

```
main_Status_OID = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.3.23.1.1.1.0'

# Set the OIDs according to the Level argument
if Level == 1:
    Server_IP_OID = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.3.23.1.1.2.1.2.1'
    Secret_OID = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.3.23.1.1.2.1.6.1'
    Status_OID = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.3.23.1.1.2.1.4.1'
elif Level == 2:
    Server_IP_OID = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.3.23.1.1.2.1.2.2'
    Secret_OID = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.3.23.1.1.2.1.6.2'
    Status_OID = '1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.3.23.1.1.2.1.4.2'
else:
    return -1

# Set the Main RADIUS Authentication Enable/Disable field
g = setCmd(SnmpEngine(), 
           CommunityData('admin', mpModel=1),
           UdpTransportTarget((Device_IP, 161)), 
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(main_Status_OID), Integer32(main_Status)))

next(g)

# Set the IP Address field of the Primary/Secondary RADIUS Server
g = setCmd(SnmpEngine(), 
           CommunityData('admin', mpModel=1),
           UdpTransportTarget((Device_IP, 161)), 
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(Server_IP_OID), IpAddress(Server_IP)))

next(g)

# Set the Shared Secret field of the Primary/Secondary RADIUS Server
g = setCmd(SnmpEngine(), 
           CommunityData('admin', mpModel=1),
           UdpTransportTarget((Device_IP, 161)), 
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(Secret_OID), OctetString(Secret)))

next(g)

# Set the Admin Status field of the Primary/Secondary RADIUS Server
g = setCmd(SnmpEngine(), 
           CommunityData('admin', mpModel=1),
           UdpTransportTarget((Device_IP, 161)), 
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(Status_OID), Integer32(Status)))

next(g)
```

I have tried to turn the ObjectType into a tuple of (ObjectIdentity(OID), Value) pairs but I got some errors. Is it possible to reduce all the "standalone" set commands into one set commands of 4 pairs ?

By the way, the if at the top of the code block is used to set the OID values so that I would be set to the right row in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pysnmp prospective you [surely can](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/setcmd.html#set-command):

```
...
g = setCmd(SnmpEngine(), 
    CommunityData('admin'),
    UdpTransportTarget((Device_IP, 161)), 
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(main_Status_OID), Integer32(main_Status))),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(Server_IP_OID), IpAddress(Server_IP))),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(Status_OID), Integer32(Status))
)

next(g)
```

Hopefully, your SNMP agent supports that as well.

Comment: Thanks. First of all, I see that you omitted the 'mpModel=1' from the CommunityData definition. Was there a purpose behind this ? Is there a certain limit to the number of OID value pairs that I can generate in one command ?

Comment: `mpModel=1` is the default which means to use SNMP v2c. That's why I dropped it. There is no explicit limit on the number of OIDs. However, there is some limit on the SNMP message size and SNMP agent capability to handle many OIDs. So your mileage may vary. I think you should be able to operate on 20-30 OIDs at once. On the other hand it may also depend on the OIDs, e.g. how expensive they are to produce for the Agent.